# RedisPub Sub blocking IO

Tags: python, node.js, redis, io

I've got a nodejs webclient communicate vi redis pubsub with other middleware services .

Middleware service written with Python .First hours we have no any problem but after several hours , when I PUBLISH a channel from nodeJs client python service did not response anything .

NodeJs ------> (PUB) |-----CHANNEL -----| -----> (SUB) Python Service

How I can handle this problem .

My python code is shown as below ,

---

```
def RedisCheck():
  try:

    r = redis.StrictRedis(host=os.environ["REDIS_HOST"], port=6379)

    p = r.pubsub()

  /****/ 


if __name__ == "__main__":

    RedisCheck()
```

That is my redis connection code .

Best Regards .

Comment: have you checked socket connections that time? there might be a possibility your client lost connection.

Comment: you need to run the redis subscriber in a separate thread